# page is closing not showing any data while running

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-layout, android-volley

-------first code-----------

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
TextView textViewId, textViewUsername, textViewEmail, textViewGender;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
    //displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }


    textViewId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    textViewGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGender);


    //getting the current user
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

    //setting the values to the textviews
    textViewId.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    textViewUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
    textViewEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    textViewGender.setText(user.getGender());

    //when the user presses logout button
    //calling the logout method
    findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
        }
    });

}
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.staff_link:
            fragment = new Staff_layout();
            break;
        case R.id.student_link:
            fragment = new Student_layout();
            break;
        case R.id.vehicle_link:
            fragment = new Vehicle_layout();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    //make this method blank
    return true;
}


}
```

when i place only the second code it is running and showing data in the layout but after adding the first code it is closing

------second code---------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity


{
TextView textViewId, textViewUsername, textViewEmail, textViewGender;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }


    textViewId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    textViewUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    textViewGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGender);


    //getting the current user
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

    //setting the values to the textviews
    textViewId.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    textViewUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
    textViewEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    textViewGender.setText(user.getGender());

    //when the user presses logout button
    //calling the logout method
    findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
        }
    });


}


}
```

when the first code is executed it is not running at all but when the second code executed it is executing how to add navigationslider to the second code or how to rectify the first code

log
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jishwanth.two/com.example.jishwanth.two.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1489)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6178)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                      at com.example.jishwanth.two.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2634)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1489) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6178) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: Can you add Log data to your question?

Comment: `it is closing` what is closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourlog cat says that the Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. 
So inside your values folder in styles.xml replace the first line with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Reason: since you are using your own toolbar so you have to remove the default toolbar.